# Unity: How to speed up score countdown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

A quick question. I am playing with a small game from some tutorials but wanted to add a score that reduces each second. I managed to do so by the code provided below, but the score only lowers with 1 seconds at a time. I want to speed it up somehow, so it can drop each second by let's say 150. I tried a few things, but they didn't work and most of them didn't even record a change on the GUI inside the game. Any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameOverScreen;
    public Text Score;
    public Text Highscore;

    bool gameOver;
    private int score = 12000;

    void Start () {
        FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().OnPlayerDeath += OnGameOver;
    }


    public void Update () {

        Score.text = Mathf.Round(score - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad).ToString();

        if (gameOver)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
            }
        }
    }

     void OnGameOver()
    {
        gameOverScreen.SetActive (true);
        Highscore.text = Mathf.Round(score - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad ).ToString();

        gameOver = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself. Make a function to get the score.

```
int GetScore() {
    return score - (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * 150;
}
```

And then use it.

```
void Update() {
    Score.text = GetScore().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly how I wanted. I didn't know you can do that with (int).

Answer (score 1):

Change this part

```
 Score.text = Mathf.Round(score- Time.deltaTime*150).ToString();
```

--

```
public void Update () {

            Score.text = Mathf.Round(score- Time.deltaTime*150).ToString();

            if (gameOver)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
                }
            }
        }
```